# Taking screenshot of website with python results in blank page

Tags: python, linux, web

So I'm trying to take a screenshot of a website using a python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Screenshot(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self._loaded = False
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

    def capture(self, url, output_file):
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.wait_load()
        time.sleep(120)
        # set to webpage size
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
        # render image
        image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        painter = QPainter(image)
        frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()
#        print 'saving', output_file
        image.save(output_file)

    def wait_load(self, delay=0):
        # process app events until page loaded
        while not self._loaded:
            self.app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(delay)
        self._loaded = False

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self._loaded = True

    s = Screenshot()
    s.capture('http://csgo-stats.com/maschs/', 'csgo-stats.png')
```

It works on almost every page but on the site csgo-stats.com/maschs (which is my profile page) it just results in a blank page without the info on the page. When I open the page in my browser it takes a few seconds to load and it shows everything properly. The result looks like this: [image: csgo-stats]

I'm using the Raspberry Pi and Python 2.7

Comment: Have you considered using the "Steam Web API" to retrieve the information in an officially sanctioned manner instead of a literal screen-scrape?

Comment: this would be a solution, but I didn't find any complete python steam web api solutions and the website already displays it pretty nicely. Or is there any easy way to use the "Steam Web API" with python?

Answer (score 1):

Your browser interface may fire the "page loaded" event when it believes that all the content has settled and all initial Javascript code has run.

The page you are trying to capture may be populating the contents with additional data based on asynchronous requests issued at load time.

You have to either figure out how to wait for enough events and state, or just blindly wait until you think it is sufficiently updated.

Comment: Also: It might be possible to verify this by opening Network tab of developer tools as the page loads, and then compare timing of when the "page loaded" event fires, to when you can see the whole page.

Comment: Just waiting didn't help. It just doesn't seem to load at all. I'm probably just going to try my luck with the official steam web api instead.

Comment: This is the right answer.. consider registering a timer once you get the page loaded signal. A good range on a modern consumer CPU is ~3000ms. With a raspberry pi I would expect something longer.

It's not an elegant/perfect solution but I haven't found anything better.

I'm currently using QtWebKit as well, just in C++ and this was how I solved the problem